# MYSQL how to a order by in a join tables

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL that is working but it's not ordering by DESC like I want to. It's completely ignoring the order by command.

this is the sql

```
SELECT Sales.saleId, Sales.tax, Sales.subtotal, Sales.total, Sales.created as createdTemp, Users.firstName, Users.lastName
            FROM Sales
            JOIN Users
            ON Sales.userId = Users.userId
            JOIN Companies
            ON Companies.companyId = 1
            ORDER BY Sales.saleId DESC
```

Comment: can you set up a sqlfiddle ? It looks correct

Comment: is saleId an Integer field? what does it mean that it doesn't order correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT Sales.saleId, Sales.tax, Sales.subtotal, 
         Sales.total, Sales.created as createdTemp,
         Users.firstName, Users.lastName
            FROM Sales
            JOIN Users
            ON Sales.userId = Users.userId
            JOIN Companies
            ON Companies.companyId = 1
) AS s
ORDER BY s.saleId DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I discovered that the plugin dataTables auto sort the data. For any having this problem they could remove the auto sorting of this plugin by doing this.     $('.tableClass').dataTable({
        /* Disable initial sort */
        "aaSorting": []
    });